# Who sets the variable IS_MASTER in chef recipes or bash

Tags: bash, chef-infra

This might seem a little stupid but I see the variable IS_MASTER being used in a chef template `templates/default/server.sh.erb` as:

```
$ grep -r IS_MASTER .
./templates/default/server.sh.erb:    if [ $IS_MASTER -eq 1 ]
./templates/default/server.sh.erb:    if [ $IS_MASTER -eq 1 ]
```

The above implies the variable is only being read and not written by anyone. Nowhere in the entire code-repository, this variable is being written. So I am wondering if this is a bug or some hidden variable in chef or shell. Does anyone know?

1. Quick Google search gives nothing.
2. Inspection of the script's-invocation gives nothing.
3. Original author of the above code is no longer around to help me with this.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Sorry I couldn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program relies on using data as a variable. There is another script that reads out a JSON configuration spitted out by some other program and then sets all the variables. It also capitalizes those variables before setting. The JSON data has a variable `is_master` in it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Bash environment variable, not an Erb template variable (looks like `<%= @something %>`), so as far as Chef is concerned that's just text that gets written to disk. Check any init scripts or `/etc/default/` files for it perhaps?